# Exercise on Venn diagrams and cardinality.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The survey is a university indicates that to:

- 29 students liked the meringue.
- 23 like vallenato.
- 40 they like classical music.
- 10 they like classical music and meringue.
- 13 they like classical music and vallenato.
- 5 they like vallenato and meringue.
- 3 they like merenge, vallenato and classical music.
  If a total of 70 students were interviewed, calculate:

$a)$ The number of students who only like classical music.

$b)$ The number of students who like meringue and vallenato, but not classical music.

$c)$ The number of students who did not like meringue, vallenato or classical music.

I made the following diagram to guide me,

[image]

For the $ a) $ I think that for those who only like classical music it would be $ | C | - | A \cap C | - | B \cap C |-|A\cap B\cap C| = 40-13-10-3 = 14 $.

Some help for others, could you correct me if I did something wrong in the $ a) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've made some mistakes in transferring the given data into the Venn diagram. You're told that there are 10 people who like classical music and meringue, and these *include* the people who like all three. There should thus only be $10 - 3 = 7$ people who like classical and meringue but not vallenato, where you've indicated 10 in the Venn diagram. Similarly for the other combinations. Otherwise, your *approach* (not your calculation) for a) is correct based on the Venn diagram, but incorrect based on the notation, which should be $\lvert C\rvert - \lvert A \cap C\rvert - \lvert B \cap C\rvert \mathbin{\color{red}+} \lvert A \cap B \cap C\rvert$ (by inclusion-exclusion), or equivalently $\lvert C\rvert - \lvert A \cap B' \cap C\rvert - \lvert A' \cap B \cap C\rvert - \lvert A \cap B \cap C\rvert$ (as the Venn diagram would suggest), where $X'$ denotes the complement of $X$.

Comment: So we would have that those who like classical music are only 14, those who like merengue and vallenato but not classical 2 and finally those who do not like any 0? I am right?

Comment: I'd double check your calculations; $40 - 7 - 10 - 3 = 40 - 10 - 13 + 3 \neq 14$, but you're right about b)

Comment: I don't understand, if this is how you do it, give 20. But in the diagram you have to give 14, right? Could you explain to me.

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Ah okay. So, if I understood correctly, the result for the $ a) $ is 20, for the $ b) $ it is 2, and for the $ c) $ it is 0. Correct?

Comment: How are you getting 0 for c)?

Comment: I don't think it is wrong. If I am not wrong, you can calculate those who only like the meringue that would be 14, and only the vallenato that would be 5, and we have that the only ones who like the classic are 20. If I add all that it gives me 39and it is Rest at 70 gives me 31. And those don't like any of the 3. I'm right?

Comment: Your values for only meringue and only vallenato are wrong. Remember that you need to fix multiple of the figures you already have in the Venn diagram.

Comment: At the intersection of A and B there is a 2, in that of A with C there is a 7, in that of B with C there is a 10, and in the intersection of all there is a 3. Therefore, if we calculate those that only Like merengue it gives $ 29-2-3-7 = $ 17 and those who only like vallenato gives $ 23-2-3-10 = $ 8, therefore, if we add everything that is, $ 17 + 2 + 3 + 7 + 8 + 10 + 20 = 67 $ and if we subtract it from 70 it gives 3. And those are the ones who do not like any of the 3.

Comment: Exactly! Good job

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate your help :).